# How to Wrap the tooltip in properties view table entries

Tags: java, eclipse, tooltip, swt

I have an default TabbedPropertySheetPage with TableViewer and it works well.
The Property View is opening on right side of the window , but the tooltip on the table cell is not showing all the text in the table cells.

Is there any possibility to wrapp and show the tooltip for cell data ?

Comment: Use HTML for your tool-tip strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following snippet referred in JFace page. [JFace snippet link](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JFaceSnippets)

Refer the **Snippet037 - Fancy Custom Tooltips**. (Supports only in JFace 3.3 version)

```
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ArrayContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.CellLabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewerToolTipSupport;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewerColumn;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerCell;
import org.eclipse.jface.window.ToolTip;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

/**
 * Explore JFace custom tooltips drawing.
 *
 */

public class Snippet037FancyCustomTooltips {

    private static class FancyToolTipSupport extends ColumnViewerToolTipSupport {

        protected FancyToolTipSupport(ColumnViewer viewer, int style,
                boolean manualActivation) {
            super(viewer, style, manualActivation);
        }

        @Override
        protected Composite createToolTipContentArea(Event event,
                Composite parent) {
            Composite comp = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
            GridLayout l = new GridLayout(1, false);
            l.horizontalSpacing = 0;
            l.marginWidth = 0;
            l.marginHeight = 0;
            l.verticalSpacing = 0;

            comp.setLayout(l);
            Browser browser = new Browser(comp, SWT.BORDER);
            browser.setText(getText(event));
            browser.setLayoutData(new GridData(200, 150));

            return comp;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isHideOnMouseDown() {
            return false;
        }

        public static final void enableFor(ColumnViewer viewer, int style) {
            new FancyToolTipSupport(viewer, style, false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        TableViewer v = new TableViewer(shell, SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        v.getTable().setLinesVisible(true);
        v.getTable().setHeaderVisible(true);
        v.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
        FancyToolTipSupport.enableFor(v, ToolTip.NO_RECREATE);

        CellLabelProvider labelProvider = new CellLabelProvider() {

            @Override
            public String getToolTipText(Object element) {
                return "<html><body>Tooltip ("
                        + element
                        + ")<br /><a href='http://www.bestsolution.at' target='_NEW'>www.bestsolution.at</a></body></html>";
            }

            @Override
            public Point getToolTipShift(Object object) {
                return new Point(5, 5);
            }

            @Override
            public int getToolTipDisplayDelayTime(Object object) {
                return 2000;
            }

            @Override
            public int getToolTipTimeDisplayed(Object object) {
                return 5000;
            }

            @Override
            public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
                cell.setText(cell.getElement().toString());
            }
        };

        TableViewerColumn column = new TableViewerColumn(v, SWT.NONE);
        column.setLabelProvider(labelProvider);
        column.getColumn().setText("Column 1");
        column.getColumn().setWidth(100);
        String[] values = new String[] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",
                "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten" };
        v.setInput(values);

        shell.setSize(200, 200);
        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

[image: Snippet output]